# Como ler um arquivo js export default

Tags: javascript, react

Bom dia, estou desenvolvendo um componente com react, mas não estou conseguindo atribuir valores de um arquivo que criei para informações default. Exemplo:

criei este arquivo menu-itens.js

```
`export default {
       items:[
         {
          id: 1,
          title:'NFC-e',
          icon:'fa fa-file',
          url:'',
         },
        {
         id: 2,
         title:'NF-e',
         icon:'fa fa-file',
         url:'',
       },
      ]
    }`
```

e gostaria de realizar a leitura dessas informações no meu arquivo index.js do componente, para renderizar o componente já com os atributos.

O que fiz até agora.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import items from './menu-item';
import './styles.css';

export default function Sidebar() {
  const [repositores, setRespositories] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setRespositories(items);   
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="main-sidebar">
      <div className="container-sidebar">
        <ul>
          {items.map((repo, index) => (
            <li key={index}>{repo.title}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa tarde, consegui resolver o problema dessa forma.

```
import data from './menu-itens'


data.items.map(item => (
   <li key={item.id}>{repo.title}</li>
))
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode apenas nomear o object durante seu import, por exemplo:

index.js:

```
import items from './menu-itens';
```

Para assim fazer a leitura:

```
items.map((repo, index) => (
            <li key={index}>{repo.title}</li>
          ))
```

Comment: Boa tarde Matheus Gomes, eu tentei dessa forma, porém gera o erro que o map não é uma função, consegui atribuindo um nome à importação dessa forma.
import data from './menu-itens';
data.items.map(item => (
 <li key={index}>{repo.title}</li>
))